# Same address of two variables?

Tags: c

How can I declare two different variables (say x and y) that have the same address?

```
   printf("%p\n",&x);  /*will be same */
   printf("%p\n",&y);
```

If possible without `union`?

Comment: and you don't want pointers?

Comment: Yes. it is a way, but i want without using union.

Comment: If you don't want to use pointers, it is not possible, what you are asking is variables by reference(c++)

Comment: What your solution with pointers? I don't care what type X and Y all i care about is that they sit in same address.

Comment: Ya with reference variables you can make the parameter variable reside at the same address as the argument variable. I want to do this same thing even when not making a function call. I wish there was a way. I'm about to resort to passing an address of an argument to get around this limitation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The precise thing you asked for cannot be done using only the standard facilities of the language, but some compilers have extensions that permit it.  For instance, with GCC this might do what you want ([documentation here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Asm-Labels.html)).

```
#define ASMNAME(x) ASMNAME_(__USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, #x)
#define ASMNAME_(x,y) ASMNAME__(x, y)
#define ASMNAME__(x,y) __asm__(#x y)
int x;
extern int y ASMNAME(x);

int main(void)
{
    return !(&x == &y); /* will exit successfully */
}
```

Note well what effect this has, though: in the object file, there is only one variable, and its name is `x`.  `y` has only been declared as another name for it in the source code.  This may or may not be good enough depending on what you're trying to do.

Note also that the two variables are treated as *distinct* for optimization purposes.  For instance:

```
#define ASMNAME(x) ASMNAME_(__USER_LABEL_PREFIX__, #x)
#define ASMNAME_(x,y) ASMNAME__(x, y)
#define ASMNAME__(x,y) __asm__(#x y)
int x;
extern int y ASMNAME(x);

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int a, b;
   x = 1;
   a = x;
   y = 2;
   b = x;
   printf("a=%d b=%d x=%d y=%d\n", a, b, x, y); 
   return 0;
}
```

may well print

```
a=1 b=1 x=1 y=2
```

because the store to `y` is not considered to affect the value of `x`.

Comment: @Farseer Please read the edited answer and make sure this really does what you want.

Comment: It does. Thanks a lot, Zack!

Comment: Good job on subverting the C language. Abusing the extern keyword and a sprinkle of asm... nice solution though no doubt problematic.

Comment: @dingrite It's a very old GCC extension, not at all my invention.  The `__USER_LABEL_PREFIX__` gunk is admittedly not well documented; I think the original purpose was to make it possible to name things *without* a prefix, on systems that prefix by default.

Answer (score 8):

What @Mysticial saying is correct. Union elements share memory space. and two variables in union have same start address. following is my example program and its output may help you to understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>
union u{
 int x;
 int y;
};
union u a;
int main(){
    printf("\n %p %p\n",&a.x, &a.y);
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
~$ ./a.out 

0x601030 0x601030
```

Additionally, as @Alon idea, in C++ you have one more kind of variable called reference variable is alias of other variable. you can create like: (you question is taged C, In C you don't have reference variables)  see below:

```
int a = 10;
int &b = a; 

+----+----+
|   10    |  <--- a = b
+----+----+  
  2002
```

if you print `&a` and `&b` then you will get `2002` same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but is this possible without Union?

Comment: That's true, but x and y are not two different variables -- the union is the variable.

Comment: Not in C. In C++ you could do it with references. In C, a variable is by definition a unique address.

Comment: as Alon commented its possible in C++. I have ne idea presently to have two variable with same address :)

Comment: @TylerMcHenry Yes correct Same I written in my answer and idea I got from Alon Thanks to him.

Comment: In the case of cpp though, references are simply restricted pointers. If all you wanted was just some sweet syntax you could of used typedef or #DEFINE

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do what you want in pure C, when you declare variables (and do something that will read/write their addresses [so that the compiler can't decide to treat them as registers]) they are allocated room in memory. You can't have 2 variables occupy the same space without cpp's glorified references or a union, you can have one variable and a number of pointers to it though:

```
type1 var1;
type2 * var2 = &var1;
```

But ultimately when I want to treat a piece of memory as different types I usually just do:

```
void * var = &something;
```

And then just use it like:

```
*(int*)var
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p=NULL;  
    *p=value1; ,
```

print it   `*p=value2;` , use it

Comment: @XTG you don't allocate memory for `*p` so assignment to `*p` is Undefined behavior. and may cause seg-fault.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan you can practically check it .

Comment: @XTG take some time think again...although you have written wrong or incomplete.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan be sure am i wrong or incomplete and try to run it.